# Initializing functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to initialize this function in MATLAB, but the syntax won't accept it since sin needs to have an input value. I'm referring to function #3:

[image: I'm referring to function #3]

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "initialize"? And of course `sin` needs an input value. Please post your code so we can understand where your problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy and paste equation (3) as is. What is needed to comply with the matlab syntax is adding parenthesis:

```
sin(x)^2 + 3 * cos(x)^2
```